# Coax cable 130 dB vs 135 dB, which one is better?

Tags: signal, interference, coax

I need to buy some coax cable for TV via satellite. I see they are marked in dB: 135, 130, 120 down to 95. Then there are multiple layers (up to 5) and shielding copper (cu) vs aluminum (alu.)

Is my understanding correct that the higher the dB number the better the cable? Is cu shield better than alu?

I assume for the core cable as well, copper is better than alu.

I need to put it in the wall, and just want the best (i.e. most future proof cable), with minimum potential interference (5G, LTE, etc.)

Comment: What application? RF? CableTV? 50 Ohm? 75 Ohm?

Comment: @LiorBilia good point, Satellite TV (updated the question)

Comment: Link to an example, please.

Comment: @jre can i put a link to the vendor here? don't want to spam...

Comment: You're asking a technical question about the stuff, not trying to sell it.

Comment: @winny, yes its mentioned on a 100 meter roll (135, 130, 120 db).

Comment: @jre i put it here https://www.lokmann.com/sat-kabel/

Comment: @winny, less is beter, so 130 db is better then the 135 db cable? (sorry I'm really complete noob)

Comment: I was wrong on attenuation. See Lorenzo's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That figure you are talking about is shielding effectiveness. In theory, bigger is better but usually more expensive *and* bulkier.

In a residential environment it doesn't really change a lot. Especially the difference between material and the kind of shielding is tricky to evaluate and depends on the kind of noise.

In TV signal distribution is usually *way* more important signal attenuation (how much you lose for each km of cable): here smaller is better.

In general copper is better than aluminum but often it doesn't really matter (unless you need to power a pole amplifier using the cable)

Comment: Well I only have one real concern, I'm depending on Internet on via LTE (and future 5G) I need to pick a cable that has best protection. Have a few concerns about interference in the future. So while pulling the cable, I might as-well put in the right (i.e. best) one.

Comment: Technically LTE *is* on the UHF band used by TV broadcast and comes in *straight from the antenna* along with the TV signal. There are specific filters to be fit on the line to remove it, cable shielding doesn't really matter.

Comment: One thing to note.  A poorly installed connector without a proper termination for the shield can reduce those shielding effectiveness (SE) numbers by a lot, going from a theoretical 135 dB to less than 35 dB of SE.

Comment: These things usually use F connectors which often simply *screw over* the jacket onto the shield. I agree that a compression fit connector would have better shield integrity